# SSRS 2008 R2 "Reset" Line Chart RunningValue Across Groups

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a stacked bar chart with a line chart overlay. The chart has 2 category groups (segment and quarter). The line chart is a RunningValue in the segment category.

I need to be able to have the line chart "reset" itself across each instance of the segment category. Right now it will treat the last point in the first grouping and the first point in the second grouping as continuous and connect the two points together with a line. I would like instead to NOT draw the line when the line crosses the category group boundary.

Picture below.

[image: line chart image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: not sure why the image is not showing. i used the image button and uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one line for each each instance of the segment category.

Comment: this could work in my case as i currently have a defined number of categories but in the general case where the number of categories is unknown at design time this wouldn't work.